# Firefox driver not taking screenshot when deployed to azure C#

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, azure-webjobs

I have this code for taking screenshot using firefox driver selenium. its working fine on local computer and when I deploy it to azure as web Job. It's not working. It's giving error below

> " WebDriver; Failed to start up socket within 45000 milliseconds.
>   Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055; at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverServer.ConnectToBrowser(TimeSpan
>   timeToWait)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverServer.Start() 
>   at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
>   desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
>   commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxBinary binary,
>   FirefoxProfile profile, TimeSpan commandTimeout)    at
>   ConsoleApplication2.Program.TakeScreenShot(String link) in
>   C:\Users\Ebryx-\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line
>   119"

My code is

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), new FirefoxProfile(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(link);
driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"D:\home\EvidenceImages\" + filename, ImageFormat.Png);
driver.Quit();
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Sure the problem isn't the headless running of Firefox?

Comment: i dont know. its running fine on local computer

Comment: Yes, because you have a screen there.

Comment: Then is there a way to take site screenshot while deployed?

Comment: I am not sure since I have used selenium, but I think that's going to be hard.